# Minimum requirements to reset Power Platform environment

Tags: reset, power-platform

I'm trying to establish what privilege level of Security Roles is the minimum required to reset sandbox Power Platform environment. Microsoft article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/reset-environment
doesn't mention what Security Role you need to be or what exact setting (settings?) inside Security Role you need to have to do that.
From what I got so far is that System Administrator can (obviously), while Basic User cannot (button is still active, you can go all the way until the end of the process where it just doesn't do anything). So, before I try to check it manually, would anybody have this already figured out or point to some resource?
Cheers!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.